# How to make a big form?

Tags: php, search

I want to make a big form with 9 fields of search (html with php/sql).

Today, I use Case When Then.

But with 9 fields, there are many combinations

For example, when I search for 5 fields.

I get back the field if there (Null if there is no) and after I execute my query.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['Liasse']))        {

    $Liasse=$_REQUEST['Liasse'];    
}
if (empty($_REQUEST['Liasse']))     {

    $Liasse=null;   
}


$Query="SELECT * FROM type where

         case 



    when :Liasse is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Item is null and :Categorie is null
    then Liasse=:Liasse

    when :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Item is null and :Liasse is null and :Categorie is null
    then Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr

    when :Item is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Liasse is null and :Categorie is null
    then Item=:Item

    when :Categorie is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Item is null and :Liasse is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie

    when :Categorie is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Liasse is null and :Item is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr 

    when :Categorie is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Item is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Liasse=:Liasse 

    when :Categorie is not null and :Item is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Liasse is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Item=:Item 


    when :Item is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null and :Categorie is null
    then Item=:Item and Liasse=:Liasse

    when :Categorie is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Item is not null and :Liasse is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr and Item=:Item

    when :Categorie is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Item is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Liasse=:Liasse and Item=:Item

    when :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Item is not null and :Categorie is null
    then Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr and Liasse=:Liasse and Item=:Item

    when :Categorie is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Item is null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr and Liasse=:Liasse

    when :Categorie is not null and :Designation_du_composant_fr is not null and :Liasse is not null and :Item is not null
    then Catégorie=:Categorie and Désignation_du_composant_fr=:Designation_du_composant_fr and Liasse=:Liasse and Item=:Item

    end";
```

Is there a faster method?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching you can use

```
MATCH (something) AGAINST ('some words' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
I read the documentation and you have the word exceeds 4 characters to be recognized and the table in MyISAM